# Create an instance in a folder Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can you please tell me how can I make the created instance be a child element of another element?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnElements : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject element;

    void Start()
    {
        element = GameObject.Find("element");
        GameObject itemObject = Instantiate(element, new Vector3(Random.Range(250.0f, 500.0f), 0, Random.Range(250.0f, 500.0f)), Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will make itemObject child of element GameObject.

```
itemObject.transform.parent = element;
```